# Script stops working after first run

Tags: javascript, jquery

So what I am trying to do is change the data in the lost column of a table using Greasemonkey.

The problem I am having is that the navigation bar of the site (has 3 links in total) uses JavaScript to load new pages (i.e. the URL doesn't change) and if you go a different page but then come back, any and all changes I had already made are lost (because the code doesn't run again) and only a refresh fixes it.
Using the `waitForKeyElements()` works on the first page load however it stops working after that. To test it out I added `.click` to `.a` and `.p`. Clicking on the first link slides it up (i.e. works properly) however it stops working after that. Same with the `.p` part. Do I have to wrap the entire thing in a loop? Or should I set a timer that executes the script every x seconds.

The code I have so far

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        changetext
// @namespace   changetext
// @include     *
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// ==/UserScript==


$('p').click(function () {
    $(this).slideUp();
});

$('a').click(function () {
    $(this).slideUp();
});

waitForKeyElements ("#row", newdata());

function newdata()
{
    document.getElementById("row").innerHTML = "<span class='text'>Test</span>";
}
```

Comment: If `newdata()` is supposed to be a callback, you shouldn't be invoking it directly. `waitForKeyElements ("#row", newdata);` (note the omitted parenthesis).

Comment: if you are manipulating the dom you should use .on

Comment: osdamv. I'm sorry but I am really new the javascript. Where should I be using .on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source of waitForKeyElements.js:

```
function waitForKeyElements (
    selectorTxt,    /* Required: The jQuery selector string that
                        specifies the desired element(s).
                    */
    actionFunction, /* Required: The code to run when elements are
                        found. It is passed a jNode to the matched
                        element.
                    */
    bWaitOnce,      /* Optional: If false, will continue to scan for
                        new elements even after the first match is
                        found.
                    */
    iframeSelector  /* Optional: If set, identifies the iframe to
                        search.
                    */
) { ... }
```

The description of `actionFunction` strongly suggests that you should pass it a function, not the result of function execution, i.e. "The code to run when...".

```
// GOOD - pass the function itself to serve as a callback
waitForKeyElements ("#row", newdata);

// BAD - calls the function once and passes the result (if any) of 
// executing the function
waitForKeyElements ("#row", newdata());
```

You could also write it as:

```
waitForKeyElements ("#row", function() {
        document.getElementById("row").innerHTML = "<span class='text'>Test</span>";
    });
```

Looking further, I think you also have a problem with your selector. The script is supposed to fire new elements which match the specified selector when they are added. **However**, you have an ID selector and there can only be one ID per document.

Try this script which uses a class name instead: http://jsfiddle.net/Lh438/

Comment: For some reason passing it as a function results in the script not working at all. I have no idea why but I have to add those brackets.

Comment: Declare `newdata` before passing it. Or, try the second syntax with an anonymous function.

Comment: Declaring the newdata first and the second syntax both have no effect.

Comment: Check out my edit; I added a small demo and another suggestion.

Comment: Hm while your example works on jfiddle it is not working for me. I don't think the site uses standard ajax or something else that is messing it up. Instead I think I should use a loop or a timer. Which one do you think would be more efficient? The one thing all pages have in common in a span with my name in it. Would it be better do a while span=myname or just a timer that checks for my name and if it is there executes the script every 100ms or something?

Comment: waitForKeyElements already uses a timer...so I'm not sure adding another timer will fix anything (and may cause more trouble). Unfortunately, I'm not that familiar with Greasemonkey scripts...sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Using a timer fixes the problem but I am not sure it is too efficient. What if I dont use the waitforKeyElements at all and just use a timer with an if statement? It is working but would it be inefficient?

Comment: One timer would probably be fine (assuming it works the way you want it to).

Comment: Ok now last question... there is something else I want to edit on a second page. Using 2 timers works perfectly fine. Is that ok to use? Its not lagging or throwing any errors.

Comment: Since this is a Greasmonkey script, I'd say it's okay to use multiple timers if that's the only way to accomplish what you want. On a normal web page, I usually try to minimize the number of timers since it is 1) harder to debug and 2) performance can start to degrade if you have a lot going on in the background. In this case, whatever works.